# Generating a Google Maps Release Key

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

So I am using the google maps api in my application. I added the activity and put the api key into the google_maps_api.xml(debug) and then went and created a different api key and put that into google_maps_api.xml under /release which I had to go to the file explorer to find. If I launch the application via the green play button in android studio, the map loads just fine. But when I generate the apk under build the map does not load. I believe this is due to the api not working. One of my concerns is that the only way to edit the google_maps_api(release) is by finding it in the explorer. All help is very much appreciated!

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/Settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewCodeActivity"
            android:label="Receipt Code"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetHelp"
            android:label="@string/get_help_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT.ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".SettingsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CodeAdder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_code_adder"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LocationPicker"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location_picker" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.CodeAdder" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

Comment: You have to change the active Build Variant to see the release-specific resources. It is usually in the lower left corner

Comment: Can you post the _build.gradle_ file of your application ?

Comment: Ok, just added the build.gradle.

Comment: What keystore do you use when building the APK ? Did you use the same keystore to generate the second Maps API key ?

Comment: I added the api key by following the link to the developer console and enter the SHA-1 Fingerprint and Package Name.

Comment: Did you check the logcat? Is there any message related to the API key being invalid ?

Comment: ok, just looked and it gave an error saying make sure that the key is enabled and make sure that it exists. Am I supposed to differentiate between the debug and release in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same Android API key for both debug and release.

Package names can be the same, but as you cannot sign your release with a debug keystore, the **certificate fingerprints should be different**.

Check that the release fingerprint is correct with the keytool command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my_release_store.keystore
```

[image: Multiple entries for the same Android API key]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio, go to "**Project**" view. You will find google_maps_api(release) under **app >> src >> release >> res >> values**

You need to add **signingConfigs** to your **build.gradle (Module:app)** file.

This is what my file contains -

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('Path\\YourReleaseKey.jks')
        storePassword 'password'
        keyAlias 'YourAlias'
        keyPassword 'password'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Also, try on multiple devices. I once had an issue due to some application setting on my device. It worked after I reset all application settings.